# $ is not defined, but only on $(function())

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

In my MVC partial view, the below does not fire:

```
$(function() {
   alert('test');
});
```

The console reports that `'$ is not defined.'`, which seems like jQuery is not referenced in the page.

However, in the same script block, I have other jQuery functions that work perfectly, so this problem seems isolated to just the `$(function())` or `$( document ).ready()` on-load functions.

Here's the complete script block in the partial view:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {
        debugger;
        alert('hi');
    });

    function updatePaymentTypes() {
        $("#paymentTypes").empty();
        $('#paymentTypes').append($('<option></option>').val("").html("- Please Select -"));
        var getVoucherPaymentTypesUrl = "@Url.Action("getVoucherPaymentTypes", "Supplier", new { id = Model.Supplier.Id, area = "Configurations" })";
        $.post(getVoucherPaymentTypesUrl, { "voucherPaymentMethodId": $("#paymentMethods").val() },
            function (data) {
                for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    var paymentType = data[i];
                    $('#paymentTypes').append($('<option></option>').val(paymentType.Id).html(paymentType.Name));

                }
                // Force event
                paymentTypeSelected();
            });
    }

    function paymentTypeSelected() {
        var getCardDetailsViewUrl = "@Url.Action("getVoucherCardDetailsView", "Supplier", new { id = Model.Supplier.Id, area = "Configurations" })";
        $.post(getCardDetailsViewUrl, { "voucherPaymentTypeId": $("#paymentTypes").val() }, 
            function (data) {
                $("#cardDetailsView").html(data);
            }).fail(function (error) {
                debugger;
            });
    }


</script>
```

The partial view is being rendered within a jQuery Accordion div, and all jQuery functions in the parent view, including the `$(function())` events all fire normally.

What could be wrong?

Comment: It may not be the problem, but never put scripts in partial views. Move it to the main view

Comment: Did you include jQuery above this script tag or below?

Comment: You call the `$(function())` immediately whereas the jQuery references in those functions only execute when the functions themselves are invoked. I would imagine that jquery.js is included in the page *after* the above `script` block.

Comment: you just define functions using jQuery, you dont run them. that does not mean jQuery is defined there.

Answer (score 0):

As most people pointed out in the comments, the problem is that the partial view is loaded before the script reference to jQuery.js has been rendered.

Make sure the script reference to jQuery is added on the top of the main view.